# Given $D:\mathbb R_{\le n}[x]\to\mathbb R_{\le n}[x], D(p)=p'$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials, linear-transformations

Let $\mathbb R_{\le n}[x]$ be the polynomial space of a degree $\le n$ with coefficients in $\mathbb R$.

Given $D:\mathbb R_{\le n}[x]\to\mathbb R_{\le n}[x]$ defined by $D(p)=p'$ (the derivative transformation).

Let $$J=\begin{bmatrix}1\\
 & 1\\
 &  & ...\\
 &  &  & ...\\
 &  &  &  & 1\\
 &  &  &  &  & 0
\end{bmatrix}\in M_{n+1}(\mathbb R)$$

1. Find ordered bases $B,C$ of $\mathbb R_{\le n}[x]$ so that $J=[D]_C^B$ (transformation matrix from the base $B$ to $C$)
2. Let $E=\{1,x,x^2,\dots,x^n\}$. Find $[D]_E^E$.
3. Find an ordered base $B$ of $\mathbb R_{\le n}[x]$ so that $J=[D]_B^B$ or prove that that such ordered base doesn't exist.

my answers:

1. as $D(p)=p'$, I tried to build some base as $B=\{x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n\}$ as i is the degree of the every vector $i\leq n$.

then I tried to differentiate $B$. I got confused with the coefficients. what is the right way of finding $B$ and $C$?

2. $[D]_E^E=\begin{bmatrix}0\\
    & 1\\
    &  & 2\\
    &  &  & ...\\
    &  &  &  & n\\
    &  &  &  &  & 0\\
    &  &  &  &  &  & 0
   \end{bmatrix}$ is that correct?
3. I think there's no such base because the only $p$ that will exist $D(p)=p'$ is $p=0$.

Comment: 1. As the last column is $0$ there is no choice for the last vector of $B$. TThen try to construct $B$ then $C$.
2. It is not correct, the derivative of $x^n$ is $n x^{\color{red} {n-1}}$. And why the last two zeroes ?
3. It is indeed the right justification :-)

Comment: i only wrote the coefficients. so n is the coefficient of $x^{n-1}$, and the last two zeros are the coefficient of $x^{n}$ and $x^{n+1}$ as $J\in M_{n+1}$

Comment: @Jneven : $M_{n+1}(\mathbb R)$ because $\mathbb R_n[X]$ has dimension $n+1$ :-)

Comment: this is was I answered in an exam and got 1/5 because "this is not a base"

Comment: @NicolasFRANCOIS In this case you obtain $$\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\
 &0& 1\\
 &  & ...\\
 &  &  & ...\\
 &  &  &  & &0&1\\
 &  &  &  &  & &0
\end{bmatrix} \neq J$$

Comment: Oups, confused :-(

Comment: @Delta-u - are answers for section 2 & 3 are correct?

Comment: Your answer for section is not correct but for section 3 it is indeed the correct answer.

Comment: can you suggest a the right answers please? would be much helpful

Comment: I added an answer do not hesitate to ask me if there is an unclear point :-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hints**

1. With $B=(b_0,\ldots,b_n)$ and $C=(c_1,\ldots,c_n)$ as $D(b_n)=\sum_i J_{i,n+1} c_i=0$ you need to have $b_n=1$ (or any constant). Then you can choose the other vectors of $B$ and adjust $C$ accordingly.

For example try $B=(x^n,x^{n-1}, \ldots, x^2,x,1)$ and $C=(nx^{n-1},(n-1) x^{n-2},\ldots,2x,1,x^n)$.

2. To compute $[D]_E^E$, for all $e_i=x^i$ you need to write $D(e_i)$ as a linear combination of the $e_j$.

For example $D(e_0)=0=\sum_{j=0}^n 0 \times e_j$ so the first column is filled with $0$.

Then $D(e_1)=1=1 \times e_0+0 \times e_1+\ldots +0 \times e_n$.

Doing so for all the basis leads to:
$$\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\  &0& 2\\  &  & \ddots\\  &  &  & \ddots\\  &  &  &  & &0&n\\  &  &  &  &  & &0 \end{bmatrix}$$

3. For the last point your justification is the correct one, you can look at the answer of Nicolas FRANCOIS for a  more precise explanation.

Comment: 1. why did you write: $C=(nx^{n-1},(n-1) x^{n-2},\ldots,2x,1,*X^n*)$. did you mean $C=(nx^{n-1},(n-1) x^{n-2},\ldots,2x,1,*0*)$?

Comment: @Jneven it is indeed $x^n$ as you need to have a base.

Comment: I think you have a mistake, as $a_{n,n+1}$ should be   $a_{n,n+1} = n-1$  and not $n$, for what I understand. as the $n+1$-th vector of $E$ is $x^n$.

Comment: @Jneven indeed it is $x^n$ and as $D(x^n)=n x^{n-1}$ the coefficient is $n$ :-).

Comment: but  $E=\{1,x,x^2,\dots,x^n\}$. the vector space is  $\mathbb R_{\le n}[x]$ be the polynomial space of a degree ***$\le n$*** - equal or $<$ $n$

Comment: Yes, so $D(e_n)=0 \times e_1 +\ldots + 0\times e_{n-2}+n \times e_{n-1}+ 0 \times e_n$ which explain the last column if I am not mistaken.

Comment: but $D$ IS THE  DERIVATIVE TRANSFORMATION

Comment: Yes it is, this is why $D(e_n) =n e_{n-1}$ where $e_k=x^k$.

Comment: ok, i understood my mistake.

Answer (score 2):

For last question : if there was a base $B$ such that $[D]_B^B$ were diagonal, then there would exist $n+1$ polynomials $P_k$, $0\le k\le n$, such that $D(P_k)=P_k$ for $0\le k\le n-1$ and $D(P_n)=0$.

In particular, $P_k$ would be equal to its derivative, which can be true only if $P_k=0$. But this can be a base only if $n=0$.

Comment: and for 1 and 2?

Comment: $n=0$ works because in this case, $J=(0)$. For $n>0$, there is at least one non null term on the diagonal of $J$, meaning that there is a eigen polynomial for the derivative operator, which, as I said before, can't be.

Comment: I meant, sections 1 and 2